# How to connect to a secure website using SSL in Java with a pkcs12 file?

Tags: java, ssl

I have a pkcs12 file. I need to use this to connect to a webpage using https protocol. I came across some code where in order to connect to a secure web page i need to set the following system properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "myTrustStore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "new_cert.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "newpass");
```

I have the p12(pkcs12) file. All I need is a truststore file.

I extracted the certificates using:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -in c:/mykey.p12 -out c:/cert.txt -nokeys -clcerts
```

Now converted the cert PEM file to der

```
openssl.exe x509 -in c:/cert.txt -outform DER -out c:/CAcert.der
```

Now adding the der file to a keystore

```
keytool -import -file C:/Cacert.der -keystore mytruststore
```

Now I have the truststore, but when I use it, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
```

Update:
 After removing certain properties and setting only the "trustStore", "trustStorePassword" and "trustStoreType" property, I got the following exception

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Please Help.

Comment: If you could post more of the stack trace (information from the stack frames, not just the exception message) I will take a look at it.

Comment: Another thing to check is that your trust store location is correctly specified; if javax.net.ssl.trustStore is specified but doesn't exist, an empty trust store is created on the fly. Your new error message makes it sound like this could be happening.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For anyone encountering a similar situation I was able to solve the issue above as follows:

1. Regenerate your pkcs12 file as follows:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in oldpkcs.p12 -out keys -passout pass:tmp
   openssl pkcs12 -in keys -export -out new.p12 -passin pass:tmp -passout pass:newpasswd
   ```
2. Import the CA certificate from server into a TrustStore ( either your own, or the java keystore in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`, password: `changeit`).
3. Set the following system properties:

   ```
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "myTrustStore");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "new.p12");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "newpasswd");
   ```
4. Test ur url.

Courtesy@ http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5296333

Comment: Writing an answer to your own question and accepting it is a bit questionable if you ask me. A bit like upvoting yourself (which of course isn't possible)

Comment: @Fredrik - seems perfectly reasonable to me. I think there's probably something about in the FAQ though.

Comment: Must the truststore really be java JKS format. Can i use keystore of .p12  ?

Answer (score 6):

I cannot comment because of the 50pts threshhold, but I don't think that the answer provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/537344/1341220 is correct.
What you are actually describing is how you insert server certificates into the systems default truststore:

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts, password: changeit)
```

This works, indeed, but it means that you did not really specify a trust store local to your project, but rather accepted the certificate universially in your system.

You actually never use your own truststore that you defined here:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "myTrustStore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Comment: I got your point. But, I am wondering, Does the statement `System.setProperty` change the default trust store or not ? Your mentioned in your answer that it is not possible to use the trust store define in the code since he/she already using the default one. Is that really true ? Then what is the point of `System.setProperty` if the default store is not changeable ?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are extracting you certificate from the PKCS #12 key store and creating a new Java key store (with type "JKS"). You don't strictly have to provide a trust store password (although using one allows you to test the integrity of your root certificates).

So, try your program with *only* the following SSL properties set. The list shown in your question is over-specified and may be causing problems.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "myTrustStore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Also, using the PKCS #12 file directly as the trust store should work, as long as the CA certificate is detected as a "trusted" entry. But in that case, you'll have to specify the `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType` property as `"PKCS12"` too.

Try with these properties only. If you get the same error, I suspect your problem is not the key store. If it still occurs, post more of the stack trace in your question to narrow the problem down.

---

The new error, "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty," could be due to setting the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property to a file that doesn't exist; if the file cannot be opened, an empty key store created, which would lead to this error.

Comment: I set only the properties you specified, now I get the following exception: 
"InvalidAlogrithmException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Comment: I just want to thank this answer because I didn't know that "using the PKCS #12 file directly as the trust store should work" and this solved my own issue

Answer (score 4):

This is an example to use ONLY p12 file it's not optimazed but it work.
The pkcs12 file where generated by OpenSSL by me.
Example how to load p12 file and build Trust zone from it...
It outputs certificates from p12 file and add good certs to TrustStore

```
KeyStore ks=KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("client_t_c1.p12"),"c1".toCharArray());

KeyStore jks=KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
jks.load(null);

for (Enumeration<String>t=ks.aliases();t.hasMoreElements();)
{
    String alias = t.nextElement();
    System.out.println("@:" + alias);
    if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias)){
        Certificate[] a = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate)a[i];
            System.out.println(x509.getSubjectDN().toString());
            if (i>0)
                jks.setCertificateEntry(x509.getSubjectDN().toString(), x509);
            System.out.println(ks.getCertificateAlias(x509));
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("init Stores...");

KeyManagerFactory kmf=KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, "c1".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf=TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(jks);

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
URL url = new URL("https://test.domain:443");   
String  keyStore = "server.p12"
String   keyStorePassword = "changeit";    
String  keyPassword = "changeit";    
String   KeyStoreType= "PKCS12";    
String   KeyManagerAlgorithm = "SunX509";    
String   SSLVersion = "SSLv3";    
public HttpURLConnection getHttpsURLConnection(URL url, String  keystore,
    String   keyStorePass,String  keyPassword, String  KeyStoreType
    ,String KeyManagerAlgorithm, String  SSLVersion)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException,
        UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl,handshake,record");

    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance(SSLVersion);
    KeyManagerFactory kmf =  KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerAlgorithm);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStoreType);
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), keyStorePass.toCharArray());
    kmf.init(ks, keyPassword.toCharArray());

     TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);
    TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = ( HttpsURLConnection)uRL.openConnection();

    return httpsURLConnection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how you can layer SSL on top of an existing socket, obtaining the client cert from a PKCS#12 file. It is appropriate when you need to connect to an upstream server via a proxy, and you want to handle the full protocol by yourself.

Essentially, however, once you have the SSL Context, you can apply it to an HttpsURLConnection, etc, etc.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStream is = ...;
char[] ksp = storePassword.toCharArray();
ks.load(is, ksp);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
char[] kp = keyPassword.toCharArray();
kmf.init(ks, kp);
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(socket, socket
    .getInetAddress().getHostName(), socket.getPort(), true);
sslsocket.setUseClientMode(true);
sslsocket.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
sslsocket.startHandshake();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following steps will help you to sort your problem out.

Steps:
developer_identity.cer <= download from Apple
mykey.p12 <= Your private key

Commands to follow:

```
    openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM

    openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in mykey.p12 -out mykey.pem

    openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.pem -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

**Final p12 that we will require is iphone_dev.p12 file and the passphrase.**

use this file as your p12 and then try. This indeed is the solution.:)

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this article may be outdated but still I would like to ask smithsv to correct his source code, it contains many mistakes, I managed to correct most of them but still don't know what kind of object x509 could be.Here is the source code as I think is should be:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class Connection2 {
    public void connect() {
        /*
         * This is an example to use ONLY p12 file it's not optimazed but it
         * work. The pkcs12 file where generated by OpenSSL by me. Example how
         * to load p12 file and build Trust zone from it... It outputs
         * certificates from p12 file and add good certs to TrustStore
         */
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( "pkcs12" );
        ks.load( new FileInputStream( cert.pfx ), "passwrd".toCharArray() );

        KeyStore jks = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
        jks.load( null );

        for( Enumeration t = ks.aliases(); t.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String alias = (String )t.nextElement();
            System.out.println( "@:" + alias );
            if( ks.isKeyEntry( alias ) ) {
                Certificate[] a = ks.getCertificateChain( alias );
                for( int i = 0; i == 0; )
                    jks.setCertificateEntry( x509Cert.getSubjectDN().toString(), x509 );

                System.out.println( ks.getCertificateAlias( x509 ) );
                System.out.println( "ok" );
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "init Stores..." );

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
        kmf.init( ks, "c1".toCharArray() );

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
        tmf.init( jks );

        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
        ctx.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null );
    }
}
```