# sending email from mac(10.6.6) using java (1.6.0_17)

Tags: java, email, macos

I am trying to send an email from my java program. It worked when I was using earlier versions of java(on my 10.5 mac), but since I got 10.6.6 I can't send email from my app. The error I am getting is

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1652)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:534)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at com.trinisoftinc.wagi.views.helpers.Mailer.sendMail(Mailer.java:55)
        at com.trinisoftinc.wagi.views.RegisterBean.registerUser(RegisterBean.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:338)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1522)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:824)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:721)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1014)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:220)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:530)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:511)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:179)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:199)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:428)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1647)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1245)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:125)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:68)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:102)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:423)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:107)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:763)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:113)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:48)
        at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:239)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:170)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
        ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this:

```
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null
```

be your problem? If not I would check that you have the correct SSL libraries after the update.

Edit:
Assuming you're using openSSL, then and "***openssl version***" should do the trick. Also check that your "**JAVA_HOME"/"JRE_HOME**" and other such java environment variables are correctly set, and maybe follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537040/how-to-connect-to-a-secure-website-using-ssl-in-java-with-a-pkcs12-file) guy's solution to a similar problem. I have the sneaking suspicion your problems are related.

Comment: I have looked at that line over and over again, but to no avail. I definitely set a password. I also tried to use apache commons-email and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I re-edited my answer so check and let me know if you solved the problem

Comment: simple solution: props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver"); will do the trick. It took the better part of the whole day to figure that out.