# Notnoop/ java-apns push

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with the notnoop/java-apns.
It refuses to send a push notification form the java server i have and i get the following error/exception:

com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: : the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
     at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:268)
     at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:173)
     at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
     at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
     at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
     at com.kaniti.server.notification.impl.AppleIphoneNotificationJob.run(AppleIphoneNotificationJob.java:221)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: : the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1612)
     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1595)
     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1521)
     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:64)
     at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:58)
     at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:161)

I'm using the same code, the same push certificate on different servers, and it is working, but not on mine! 
I cant seem to find out the cause of this problem. Has anyone experienced it before?

Answer (score 2):

The following steps will help you to sort your problem out.

Steps:
developer_identity.cer <= download from Apple
mykey.p12 <= Your private key

Commands to follow:

```
    openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM

    openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in mykey.p12 -out mykey.pem

    openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.pem -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

**Final p12 that we will require is iphone_dev.p12 file and the passphrase.**

Use this as your p12.This indeed is the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may resolve your problem with this other question : [the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537040/how-to-connect-to-a-secure-website-using-ssl-in-java-with-a-pkcs12-file)

Your problem is that Java cannot find the cert store, you may change the path of the store.