# Create a ssl connection only for mongodb

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl

I created a ssl mongodb connection like below

```
    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        return builder.sslEnabled(true).sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).build();
    }
```

but after that other external rest calls(example - getting languages for translate api google) fails and giving below error.

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not not change global properties for changing the SSL/TLS settings.

Instead create your custom `SSLContext` and initialize it with your trusted certificates and keys. Then generate the `SSLSocketFactory` from it and provide it to the `MongoClientOptions.Builder` via `socketFactory(SocketFactory socketFactory)`.

For an example that creates a `SSLSocketFactory` this way see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15183924/150978

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I add key to trust store?

Comment: There is a very simple way: use [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/).